# Log4j2 DefaultRolloverStrategy not working

Tags: log4j2

I have rollover strategy with 2 days, but the files don't get remove. Can you please let know if this log4j2 configuration is valid for rollover strategy?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">/log</Property>
        <Property name="fileName">filelog</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="LOG" fileName="${baseDir}/${fileName}.log"
            filePattern="${baseDir}/${fileName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}|%m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="${fileName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="2d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LOG" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What version of Log4j2 are you using?

Comment: The version is log4j 2.7

Comment: You can debug the problem by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` at the top of your configuration file. This will show details of what happens during rollover, what directories and files are considered for deletion and why they are eventually included (or not) in the deleted set.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line of `IfFileName` to

```
<IfFileName glob="${fileName}-*.log" />
```

You can also use `IfAccumulatedFileCount` if you like

```
<Delete basePath="${baseDir}">
    <IfFileName glob="${fileName}-*.log">
        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="2"/>
    </IfFileName>
</Delete>
```

Actually, I think the latter is better.